# Obj-c runtime: find what class another class is a property of

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

Suppose I have this:

```
@interface ThingManager : NSObject
@property Thing *aThing;
@end
```

Is there a way for `aThing` to know at runtime that it is a property of `ThingManager`?

Comment: You could have a `Thing` instance that isn't assigned to the property. And then you assign it to the property. At that point the instance has absolutely no knowledge this happened. And it shouldn't. If you need that knowledge then you need to explicitly update some appropriate state you add to the `Thing` class to track such information.

Comment: @rmaddy So you're saying that I could add a class method on `Thing` that tracks where its instances are being set as properties?

Comment: I'm saying you should add whatever it is that you wish to track. If each instance needs to know then make it an instance method. Your requirement is far too vague to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the question:

> Is there a way for `aThing` to know at runtime that it is a property of `ThingManager`?

Though not completely clear the answers so far have assumed you want `aThing` to be able to determine whether *an instance* of `ThingManger` is managing it.

So at this point we know that the `ThingManger` class knows about the `Thing` class, and you now appear to want the reverse - you ask can a `Thing` find its `ThingManager`?

However when someone answers that you comment

> So `Thing` and `ThingManager` need to know about each other? Mmmm... Bad for loose coupling.

Hmmm... How can a `Thing` ask what its `ThingManager` is if you don't want it to know about `ThingManager`s?

Is everybody's interpretation of your question wrong?

Maybe you are concerned not about loose coupling but about strong reference cycles? If the two know about each other, and create a strong cycle in doing so, then there is a risk they will keep each other alive long after the need for either by your application - is that the concern?

But that is addressed by @DrummerB - you use a weak property on `Thing` which references its  managing `ThingManager`. So it would appear that strong reference cycles are not your concern either...

Then you comment:

> Isn't there a way to see who's referencing an object at runtime?

As stated generally that is a very different question. The short answer to this is no[*].

Are you asking whether it is possible to write a method which a `Thing` can call to find the `ThingManager` that is managing it without any references being maintained between `Thing` instances and `ThingManager` instances?

If so here is an outline algorithm:

1. Have the `ThingManager` class keep a collection of all create *and alive* instances of itself. The alive requirement requires this collection be some kind of weak collection (design your own or do a search for weak collections).
2. Add a *class* method to `ThingManager` which finds the manager for a `Thing`, e.g. something like `+ (ThingManager *) managerFor:(Thing *)thing`.
3. Have your `Thing` instances call `[ThingManager managerFor:self]` when they need to know their manager.

That of course doesn't address your concern over loose coupling - the two classes must still know of each others existence...

Which brings you back to the direct solution of having `Thing` have a `manager` property. If you want to reduce the coupling you can type this property as `id`, so its any old object, or `id<SomeMinimalManagerProtocol>` so its any old object provide it implements some minimal set of management methods you've define in the protocol `SomeMinimalManagerProtocol`.

Take a look at `NSWindow` and `NSWindowController` - they *know* about each other.

HTH

---

[*] The long answer is that (Objective-)C(++) are not designed to ensure all references can be found. This is why you hear phrases such as "conservative garbage collection". There was a garbage collector for just Objective-C objects, which was supported by internal changes to the runtime, but that is now deprecated and its machinery wasn't easily accessible to applications to apply to other uses.

Comment: Right, my underlying question was indeed: `Isn't there a way to see who's referencing an object at runtime?`, and I actually wanted to know if the Objective-C runtime methods could be used for that purpose given my simple scenario. Because of loose coupling, `Thing` knowing about `ThingManager` would break loose coupling, and I wouldn't want that. So I like your solution of having a property on `Thing` which allows you to figure out what its `ThingManager` is.

Comment: I guess `[NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]` or `[NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray]` would be good choices for step 1 in your outline algorithm?

Comment: @Eric - Both those are collections which hold weak references and could be used. If you intend to go this route and expect to create and discard many `ThingManager`s remember you may need to "clean" the collection of null references.

Comment: "clean the collection of NULL references"? But what's the use of that? ["If *ptr* is NULL no operation is performed"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), right?

Comment: @Eric - your collection will gain an entry for every `ThingManager` you create, and that entry will be set to null once that object dies. Over time you could have a very large collection consisting mainly of null's - so removing them may be wise to reduce memory usage. If you're only going to create a handful of `ThingManager`s then such housekeeping is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you tell it, that it is.

You could add a ThingManager weak property to Thing and implement the setter in ThingManager like this:

```
- (void)setAThing:(Thing *)thing {
    if (_aThing != thing) {
        _aThing = thing;
        _aThing.manager = self;   // this is the relevant line
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. And how do you "tell it"?

Comment: So `Thing` and `ThingManager` need to know about each other? Mmmm... Bad for loose coupling.

Comment: There is no way to make a property "magically" know about any object that references it. If you want looser coupling, maybe you should apply the delegate pattern?

Comment: Isn't there a way to see who's referencing an object at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you have a custom setter for your `aThing` property that sets something on the `Thing` object to tell it that it is. You could have the `aThing` setter method set a property that you add to `Thing` that tells it who its manager is.